# Maven unpack transitive dependencies' JAR to a folder

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have two maven artifacts in my private repository, `com.test.Parent` and `com.test.Child`. `Child` is dependent on `Parent`.

The only thing I want Maven to do is to download the `Child` jar and everything it depends on, and then unpack it to a directory.

I was able to put together a `pom.xml` that downloads the `Child` by calling `mvn clean dependency:unpack`, however in order to download the transitive dependency I had to manually include it in the `pom`.

What I want is to call, for instance `maven initialize` and my required dependencies would be downloaded. What I have now is this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                                <artifactId>Child</artifactId>
                                <version>1.2.3</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <includes>**</includes>
                                <excludes>META-INF/**</excludes>
                                <outputDirectory>somepath/sources</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
                        <includes>**</includes>
                        <outputDirectory>somepath/depend</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
                    <artifactId>Child</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.3</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

However, when I run `mvn clean initialize`, only the Child files are downloaded and unpacked.

POM file of `com.test.Child` contains this:

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>Child</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent</artifactId>
        <version>7.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Do you see any problem with the setup? The endgame is that developers can just download one pom.xml, run `mvn <something>` and all the dependencies will be automatically downloaded and unpacked to a certain structure.

Thanks

**Edit:** 
When I delete my local Maven repository and run this pom, both `Child` and `Parent` are downloaded. So the dependency is there, but `Parent` is not picked up by the `unpack-dependencies` goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving the `<dependencies>` block outside `<plugins>`. So the final POM structure is:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        ...
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.test</groupId>
          <artifactId>Child</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.3</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

But if anyone can explain to me *why* this helps, that would be appreciated.